# WebSocket4Net in SilverLight

Tags: silverlight-4.0, websocket4net

I am trying to create a WebSocket client through [WebSocket4Net](http://www.w3schools.com/) with port 4503.However i could see the the WebSocket status only as "Connecting" as it is neither raising any exceptions nor proceeding further.I was able to throw the Exception OnError Event which states that 
**"An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions"**

Am i missing anything?. Any suggestions or link will be much helpful.Thanks in advance.

```
ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:4503/WSServer");
ws.Opened += new EventHandler<EventArgs>(ws_Opened);
ws.Open();
```

Comment: Maybe all you need is ClientAccessPolicy?

Answer (score 0):

I've been getting this kind of error today with a different type of socket library. This may be an access permissions problem in Silverlight, but on the server side, I found that I had to shut down Visual Studio, and then launch it with admin permissions in order to start up the service. It's going to be something like that. If it is a Silverlight access permissions thing, you will want to try running it out of browser and turning on elevated trust.